# MySQL Workbench ALTER bug?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Hello everyone im currently using the latest version of MYSQL workbench and i have successfully hooked up my database and successfully created a table called , "**User**" as shown below:

```
ID INT(11),
PASSWORD VARCHAR (255),
F_NAME VARCHAR (255),
L_Name VARCHAR (255),
Address VARCHAR (255),
```

However im trying to practice altering columns and have currently run into a big problem. Every time i run a ALTER statement MYSQL Workbench is throwing out an error which says "**syntax error: unexpected 'VARCHAR'(varchar)**"

The statement im trying to pass when getting this error is "**ALTER TABLE User MODIFY ID VARCHAR(255);**" as im trying to change the ID data-type to VARCHAR instead of INT. If anyone could help me then that would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: Just tried to add 'MODIFY COLUMN' instead and im still getting the exact same error message.

Answer (score 4):

Okay guys i found the solution for anyone else who comes across this problem when trying to learn MYSQL Workbench ALTER statements.

Basically the format that worked is to basically use "**ALTER TABLE `User` 
CHANGE `ID` `ID` VARCHAR(255);**".

Firstly i initially did not have my column and table names (shown in grey highlight within example above) surrounded in `` grave accents; and the second point was that i needed to specify the first column that i wanted to select ,which was "ID" and then next was to specify what i then wanted to then change that columns name into , in my case keeping it the same (hence the two ID'S shown in example')

Hope this helped , i thought sharing the solution would be useful to others.

Comment: Yes you are correct: First this shows up with error alter table field modify column name varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL;   But then this as you say: 
alter table field change column name name VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL;  Doesn't they both work. So surely its a bug ?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you are not collapsing the size of column in "modify" command.
You can only increase size.